# Can I omit "be" here?

Tags: grammar

I am writing an academic paper with my colleague (very good English, but not native speaker), who wrote:

> One solution are A systems, which offer high resolution, but at the cost of B and C that have to carefully aligned and calibrated to one another.

For me, from a grammar perspective:

> One solution are A systems, which offer high resolution, but at the cost of B and C that have to **be** carefully aligned and calibrated to one another.

Is it appropriate to omit **be** here? Which version is more natural in American English?

Comment: There are other possible wordings that would be OK, but your first example isn't one of them.

Comment: @HotLicks Didn't get your point... What did you mean by "possible wordings"?

Comment: (There is also a possible problem with the count of "One solutions are", but I'm guessing you elided something there.)

Comment: Possible wordings -- you gave two.  There are others.

Comment: @HotLicks Right, I did elided the previous paragraph. Our logic is, this "solution" points to certain type of system ("A systems"), so we used "are" here. And what did you mean by "two"? We intent to only mention "B" and "C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your correction is correct.  Without the auxiliary *be*, the infinitive is incomplete, so that the  relative clause is grammatically malformed.

You passed over another fault;

> One solution **are** A systems,  ...

As the clause is written, the subject is “one solution”, which is singular.  So the verb must be singular.  The plural noun phrase complement cannot drag the verb into the plural.

You could reverse the sentence, with *A systems* as the subject.  Then the verb would rightly be singular.

> “A systems **are** one solution” would in that case be correct.

Comment: That looks very garden-pathy. 'One solution is to use _A-Systems_, ...'.

Comment: Yes, that works fine, too.